# How much swearing is there in Modern Warfare 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I am thinking about getting Modern Warfare 2 for PC. I don't care that much about violence unless it is something extremely graphic like someone being tortured. Although, my parents are *extremely* uptight about swearing. I think it would be fine if they only swore about 3-5 times per level.

How much swearing is in each level (in English)

Comment: Depends how well you're playing, normally.

Answer (score 7):

In single player there's not much. Soldiers are supposed to shoot, not talk.

As far as I can remember the story there's a bit of swearing on the radio throughout the whole mission, but a lot less than 3-4 times per level. There are plenty of levels with normal mission briefings and instructions and without any bad language.

However, you'll probably have to stay away from multiplayer games, unless you disable voice and text chats. People in CoD are no soldiers. They love trash talk in MP games and muting them completely is probably the best idea. (In CoD, I have voice chats muted at all times, although I don't care about language. Listening to those guys is just a real pain.) Also cheaters are usually getting insulted. And there are a lot of them.

To mute voice chat: `Multiplayer > Options > Voice Volume` set this to 0
To disable text chat: put `cg_chattime 0` in your config located at
`$:\path-to-steam\steamapps\common\call of duty modern warfare 2\players\config_mp.cfg`

Enjoy CoD free of swearing.

Comment: At least on the xbox, it is extremely quick and easy to mute individual players as well. That way you can mute most people and still talk to the occasional reasonable human being. Hard to make friends if everybody's muted, so there's another option.

Comment: On PC you don't want to make friends with those guys. Human beings are very very rare and for someone trying to stay away from swearing I don't recommend to try to make friends in CoD. Paul pretty much confirmed it in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [**dly answer**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/298453/how-much-swearing-is-there-in-modern-warfare-2/298456#298456) that the single player gameplay doesn't contain excessive amount of swearing and it is more prominent in the multiplayer, but **I must point out that Modern Warfare 2 is one of the most controversial video game of its time.**

Most **Call of Duty** games contains some kind of indication, cutscene or gameplay of torture, but **Modern Warfare 2** managed to surpass them with is 4th mission called No Russian, in which

> the player partakes in a terrorist attack against an Airport and participate in the massacre of hundreds of civilians. This Mission was based on the [2008 Mumbai terrorist attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Mumbai_attacks).

Due to the graphic content **Modern Warfare 2** was subject to censorship in international versions of the game. In this regard only playing the multiplayer part of the game, might be more acceptable for younger people than playing the single-player campaign especially the with the social features turned off. Truth to be told its much more enjoyable that way too, **Call of Duty** is one of the games, where the player base can be excessively toxic.

If you decide to play the game, there is an option to skip this level at the start of the single-player campaign:

[image: Disturbing Content Notice]

Comment: I don't know whether it's worth adding or not, but if you do elect to take part in this mission, you can do so as an observer - there's nothing to force you to take an active part, regardless of what you see happen around you.  I simply walked through this part of the game and picked up the action when appropriate.

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ - You would still be a witness to the civilian massacre. The OP's parents would most likely want to avoid exposing their child(ren) to such content, based on the original question.

Comment: Well, age ratings are there for a reason....

Comment: Observing, skipping or playing - it doesn't matter. I usually just walked by as observer when I played it.  Also @Pᴇᴛᴇ is right. This game, like any other CoD, has its age rating for a reason. Not just because of that one level, though.